# Passing a closure as a init parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, init-parameters

I'm trying to convert an Objective-C code snippet I found on [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html) article. Here's the original code.

**.h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^TableViewCellConfigureBlock)(id cell, id item);

@interface ArrayDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)anItems
     cellIdentifier:(NSString *)aCellIdentifier
 configureCellBlock:(TableViewCellConfigureBlock)aConfigureCellBlock;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@interface ArrayDataSource ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *cellIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, copy) TableViewCellConfigureBlock configureCellBlock;

@end


@implementation ArrayDataSource

- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)anItems
     cellIdentifier:(NSString *)aCellIdentifier
 configureCellBlock:(TableViewCellConfigureBlock)aConfigureCellBlock
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.items = anItems;
        self.cellIdentifier = aCellIdentifier;
        self.configureCellBlock = [aConfigureCellBlock copy];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Here's my attempt.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class TableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var items: [AnyObject]
    var cellIdentifier: String
    var TableViewCellConfigure: (cell: AnyObject, item: AnyObject) -> Void

    init(items: [AnyObject]!, cellIdentifier: String!, configureCell: TableViewCellConfigure) {
        self.items = items
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        self.TableViewCellConfigure = configureCell

        super.init()
    }

}
```

But I get an error at this line `self.TableViewCellConfigure = configureCell` saying **Use of undeclared type 'TableViewCellConfigure'**.

I tried another way. Instead of declaring a variable for the closure, I declared it as a typealias.

```
typealias TableViewCellConfigure = (cell: AnyObject, item: AnyObject) -> Void
```

But then I get a new error at the same line above saying **'TableViewDataSource' does not have a member named 'TableViewCellConfigure'**.

Can anyone please help me out to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Surely your `init` should read `init(items: [AnyObject]!, cellIdentifier: String!, configureCell: TableViewCellConfigure)` rather than `configureCell: TableViewDataSource`

Comment: @Grimxn Oh Shit! Good catch. I changed it but now I get a new error. **Use of undeclared type 'TableViewCellConfigure**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have confused TableViewDataSource with TableViewCellConfigure in your `init`. This compiles fine for me:

```
typealias TableViewCellConfigure = (cell: AnyObject, item: AnyObject) -> Void // At outer level

class TableViewDataSource: NSObject/*, UITableViewDataSource */ { // Protocol commented out, as irrelevant to question

    var items: [AnyObject]
    var cellIdentifier: String
    var tableViewCellConfigure: TableViewCellConfigure // NB case

    init(items: [AnyObject], cellIdentifier: String!, configureCell: TableViewCellConfigure) {
        self.items = items
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        self.tableViewCellConfigure = configureCell

        super.init()
    }

}
```

Note also that you used uppercase for the property name `tableViewCellConfigure` - I've changed it, as it was confusing me, and, possibly, you!

Comment: No problem! Almost certainly a case of 'a fresh pair of eyes' being needed!